# Geronimo FTP Server on Fedora 19

Tags: configuration, fedora, apache-mina, geronimo, eclipse-kepler

I am trying to use the FTP server (factory) in Geronimo 3.0.1 on Fedora 19, in eclipse kepler. I have the following import which produces no error:

```
import org.apache.mina.*;
```

However, when I declare

```
FTPServerFactory ftpFactory;
FTPServer ftpServer;
```

neither of FTPServer and FTPServerFactory is resolvable. The usual eclipse hints in the editor, which are very cool, offer no help in this case. My build path has the mina-core.jar (This is the only MINA jar that I find in /usr/share/java/apache-mina). The build path dialog flags errors, not explicitly for mina, stating the the following are missing:

```
org.eclipse.JRE_CONTAINER/
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.uio.launcher.StandardVMType/
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.25.x86-64
```

I suspect that my installation is missing other mina jars and am at a loss for the three errors above except that the last one is strange given that the that the build path has

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0
```

My environment is all relatively new, so there could be problems in a number of places. Any advice on where to start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened when I logged in. Please disregard the empty question.
I have the following, which does not produce errors.

```
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpException;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpReply;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpRequest;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpSession;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.Ftplet;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpletContext;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.FtpletResult;
import org.apache.ftpserver.listener.ListenerFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.ssl.SslConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.*;
import org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.BaseUser;
```

My build path includes

```
ftpserver-core-1.06.jar - /usr/share/java/apache-ftpserver/common/lib
```

A code fragment follows

```
//Add the user to the FTP server as well.
PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("myusers.properties"));
userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());
org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager um = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
user.setName(newCredentials.getUserID());
user.setPassword(ConfigurationValues.get("ftpGenericPassword"));
new File(ConfigurationValues.get("ftpFilesRoot")+newCredentials.getUserID());
user.setHomeDirectory("ftproot");
um.save(user);
```

I hope this is of use. Takes a little burrowing to sort it out.

Comment: @admin I was editing an answer to a posted question (not mine), logged in with google, and posted my answer (I thought). Instead I got the above, which belongs with the original question